# AWS Lambda - Can't open lib 'FreeTDS'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc, aws-cloud9

I'm facing issue with getting FreeTDS working on AWS' Lambda. Currently I'm stuck with this error.

```
[ERROR] Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

My setup is as following. Zip packages is built using Cloud9. `lbtdsodbc.so` is present in specified .ini directory

Directory from which I compiled that dependencies (`./configure, make, make install`)

```
user@user:/tmp/lambda_2 $ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  9 ec2-user ec2-user  144 Dec  3 17:36 .
drwxrwxrwt 22 root     root     4096 Dec  3 17:36 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   97 Dec  2 22:01 bin
drwxrwxr-x  7 ec2-user ec2-user   67 Dec  2 22:15 freetds
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  210 Dec  2 22:01 include
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user  287 Dec  2 22:01 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user    6 Dec  2 22:01 ODBCDataSources
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  150 Dec  3 17:17 odbc.ini
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  130 Dec  3 17:29 odbcinst.ini
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user   88 Dec  3 15:25 python
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user   17 Dec  2 22:01 share
```

odbc.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = Alternative driver for MS SQL Server
Trace = N
#Server = ntmachine.domain.com
#Port = 1433
TDS Version = 7.3
~
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /lambda_2/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
#Setup = ./freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
#UsageCount = 1
```

Zip packaged with `zip -r9` has the above `-ls` structure.

Python snippet:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER={self.server};PORT=1433;DATABASE={self.database};UID={self.username};PWD={self.password};TDS_Version=7.3;')
```

Any help will be super appreciated!

Comment: Does this help? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package?

Comment: @Brian, I got and error `Unable to import module 'function': libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` even though `libodbc.so.2` is within the zip

Comment: I re-arranged the zip package and got: `[ERROR] Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Comment: Are you are doing this on the proper EC2 (ami: amzn-ami-hvm)? The binaries must be for the specific environment..if it works on your local machine, then it very likely won't work in Lambda. I strongly encourage following that article as it covers obtaining all required libraries as well as pathing concerns. It's using freetds as an example so should be fast. I ran into this a couple years ago, not with FreeTDS, but other binaries, and had written this up (https://github.com/brianslattery/aws-lambda-authorizer-py), but I'd start with the AWS article.

Comment: Yes, I followed the article but on Cloud9 as I couldn't find amzn-ami-hvm.

Comment: I would try with an Amazon Linux 2 image then.

Comment: I was getting multiple errors with `sudo yum install freetds` while using AMI